# How to force a block to take all height of remaining screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Look, i i have a structure like that in my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                ХЕДЕР
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <section class="первая секция контента">
                    ПЕРВАЯ СЕКЦИЯ КОНТЕНТА
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                ФУТЕР
            </div>
        </footer>   
    </div>
</body>
```

I made my content part to take all the remaining screen between header and footer like that:

```
.container{
    max-width: 1170px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

[image]

As u see, container is in my content block, but when i set min-height: '100%', it does not takes 100% of my content part, why that happens and how to make it using min-height, not using flex?
[image]

I mean, i want my container to take all the space by the end of screen, pushing footer down.

Comment: A (min-)height in percentage only works, if the parent element has an explicit height. Which is not the case for your container, that only has an implicit height resulting from the flex element growing. _"and how to make it using min-height, not using flex"_ - why such a requirement, in 2023?

Comment: Okey, how to make my container to take all the space by the end of screen, pushing footer down.

Comment: Add `display: flex` to `.content`?

Comment: By using `html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }` with `.wrapper { min-height: 100%; margin:0 auto; }` then you can also use vertical height in % , or ofcourse in vh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- `min-height: 100vh;` doesn't work ( at least in my experience it doesn't work)
So use `height: 100vh;` Yet, it isn't the optimal approach due to a possible overflow of the "content". Or use also ( as I used in this example ) `height: 100%;` and `margin: 0;`.

2-But I would recommend using flex. You will use it much more and better learn it.
I would recommend reading this article which explains the solution to your exact problem using flex : [The article](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-make-a-div-to-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space.php#:%7E:text=Answer%3A%20Use%20the%20CSS3%20flexbox,in%20all%20major%20modern%20browsers.)

Here is how I would solve your problem using flex:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .wrapper{
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .wrapper .header{
            flex: 0 1 auto;
            background: #7e8aa0;
        }
        .wrapper .content{
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            background: #dbdfe7;
        }
        .wrapper .footer {
            flex: 0 1 100px;
            background: #7e8aa0;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <header class="header">
              <div class="container">
                  ХЕДЕР
              </div>
          </header>
          <div class="content">
              <div class="container">
                  <section class="первая секция контента">
                      ПЕРВАЯ СЕКЦИЯ КОНТЕНТА
                  </section>
              </div>
          </div>
          <footer class="footer">
              <div class="container">
                  ФУТЕР
              </div>
          </footer>   
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was that you used "**min-height: 100vh**" on the wrapper which gives it an undefined height because it can be infinitely above that.

Try using "**height: 100vh**" instead that worked for me.

But I do not recommend this method as it overflows outside the wrapper because the "content" will have the same height as the wrapper itself, not considering the header and footer that are also in the wrapper, and this will cause the header and footer to overflow because there is no space left for them.

So I think your best option is to stick with the **flex box** as it was made for this kind of stuff.